# Redis password for AWS ElastiCache

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am using KUE, on EC2, and setting up an external ElastiCache Redis storage. It appears ElastiCache does not use password (auth), but instead relies on Security Groups. So do I need to leave the redis password (???) param empty?

```
redis: {
  port: 6379 //process.env.REDIS_PORT,
  host: blah.44444z.0001.usw1.cache.amazonaws.com //process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  auth: ??? //process.env.REDIS_PASS,
  options: {
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried omitting `auth` parameter?

Comment: If you answer I will mark as correct. I think putting null works also.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, there is no password for elasticache.
Unless you enable it from within the "encryption in transit", it is not available as an option.

Try to remove 'auth' and see if this works.